# What hardware is needed to run the Android emulator fast?

Tags: android, performance, emulation

My home PC is an Intel E6300 with 4GB RAM. My company PC is an Intel i5 quadcore with 4GB RAM. I ran the latest Android emulator (came with SDK) on both PC's (both running Windows 7 x64), and it was unbearably slow on both PC's.

On my home PC, I ran Windows Phone 7 emulator and it worked smoothly. I booted up with my Hackintosh on the same PC and ran iPhone simulator and it also worked smoothly.

Anyways what kind of hardware is required to run Android emulator that smoothly, i7 with 16GB RAM? Or the Android emulator is so slow that even the top-of-the line desktop CPU's are not enough and I should get a real Android device?

Comment: It's prolly not the hardware... :-\

Comment: The android emulator is pretty slow. Also, note that iphone emulator doesn't emulate the iphone hardware exactly. It runs the emulator at the speed at which your computer runs. This seems like a good idea, but it doesn't provide a good representation of what it will run like on a real phone. The android emulator is a true virtual machine (running qemu I believe) that emulates the hardware of the device

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem with your environment, it is just that the emulator is very slow. Practically I use a real phone to do my tests. It is faster and tests are more realistic. But if you want to test your application on a lot of different Android versions and don't want to buy several phones, you will have to use the emulator from time to time.

The startup of the emulator is very slow. The good thing is that you only need to start the emulator once. If the emulator is already running and you run your app again, the emulator reinstalls the app relatively quickly. Of course, if you want to know how fast it will run on a phone, it is best to test it on a real phone.

Also try to run the emulator before you start eclipse. It should start a bit faster and try to disable antivir software.

Answer (score 0):

Use ubuntu, and enable Use host GPU. It will be smooth as butter

Answer (score 0):

Change your HDD to SDD, its improve your emulator speed 20x than HDD, I have a same problem and emulator starts very slowly (maybe 5 min or higher) but now with SSD its only 10 second, without increase RAM and CPU. My cpu in i5 with 4 gig RAM